# Torchvision model cannot be loaded from storage when no GPU availabe

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I trained a torchvision mask r-cnn model on GPU and saved it to disk using `torch.save(model, model_name)`. On another machine, without GPU, I try to load it again using `torch.load(model_name)`. The model cannot be deserializised because torch does not know about device cuda:0.

How can I 'convert' such a model to be used on non-GPU environments?
I assume it is best practice to move a model to CPU before saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`torch.load()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html) has an argument `map_location` where you can specify the device. So you can use

```
torch.load(..., map_location='cpu')
```

or specify any other device to directly load it there.

Comment: oh, i did not spot this possibility, nice!